# Reputation updated globally, but not for comments?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

Friend, new to SE, contributing to WebApps just sent me a screenshot, that shows, that reputation updates are reflected on general counter (user bar at top) but not in comments mechanism:

[image]

Is this a bug or something, that is wanted / required?

**EDIT**: *This is of course temporal. After refreshing the page, limitations to writing comments were removed and comment could be written.*

Comment: what's your friends' user id or profile URL?

Comment: Well, I have to ask him, because he sent this me over an e-mail. But, this is of course temporal thing -- after refreshing the page, limitations to writing comments were all gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision whether this error is rendered is made on the server when the `add comment` link is rendered (it has an additional `data-reg="true"` attribute), since it also depends on other things that would require an additional round-trip to the server each time a user clicks this button - which we don't want.

After you've reached the required rep you need to refresh the page (so it's rendered again) to be able to add comments.